# Django: ajax & request

Tags: ajax, django, python-2.7

I don`t speak english well? but i have problem in Django.
I have models:

```
class Model1(models.Model):
    model2 = models.ManyToManyField(Model2)
    #...
class Model2(models.Model):
    model3 = models.ForeignKey(Model3)
    #...
class Model3(models.Model):
    custom = models.CharField()
```

have view

```
def simple(request, simple_id):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.is_ajax():
            if 'delete' in request.POST:
                id3 = request.POST.get('delete', '')
                Model1.objects.get(id = simple_id).model2.filter(model3__id = id3).delete()
```

That is, when submitting a form with name = "delete" Ajax have removed all the objects belonging to Model2 with the same value of the field "model3"
Here's a piece of template:

```
<form action="" method="post" id="simple">{% csrf_token %}
<input type="submit" name="delete" id="simple_delete" value="">
</form>
```

the value passed from js:

```
$('.deletebutton').click(function(){
    id = $(this).attr('data-id');
    $('#simple_delete').attr('value', id);
    $('#simple').ajaxForm();
    $('#simple_delete').click();
});
```

Well, respectively plugin jquery.form.js also connected

The problem is this - if submission without ajax all is normal, it works ... and if with Ajax is an error such as incorrect int value ... How to make it work via Ajax?

Comment: Have you tried to print the value on the server side. To see what value is being submitted via Ajax?

Comment: No. How do it? I`m beginner

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
$('.deletebutton').click(function(){
     id = $(this).attr('data-id');
     $.ajax(function(){
         type:"POST",
         url :"/your_url/",
         data:{
              'id'=id,
         }
    }).done(function(result){
         alert('your json object result render by view :'+result)
    })
```

i think it work,
and i didnt get wat you are doing in  i.e  $('#simple_delete').click();
can you please describe about that

## in view

```
obj = Model1.objects.get(id = simple_id)
model2.objects.filter(model3__id = id3).delete()
```

i just split single line query into two lines and if not working
use .select_related()

Comment: this is the correct way to achieve this, i just want to add a bit: you have to change "/your_url/" according to your urls.py file relative to the delete view. Also, if that url (as i suppose) is something similar to "/delete/<id>/", you can pass an empty data dictionary ( data:{} ) since you'll be having your simple_id already in your url (and your view appears to be configured to accept this)